# Retriveing data from Firebase database is showing null pointer exception. How?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time-data

[image]I'm retrieving some value form the RealTime database but every time it shows null pointer exception. actually i want to access all data from a child and also got new update on data when data changed via Database. My code is this, and in this code i want to append value in Text View but showing null pointer exception. please resolve my issue.

```
 db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dr=db.getReference().child("us");

      dr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    txtMsg.append((CharSequence) postSnapshot.child("name").getValue());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and my LogCat is:

```
0.481 31984-32018/com.thebhakti E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
09-02 16:51:11.891 31984-32036/com.thebhakti E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb7352a78 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xa0aa11d0 arg=0x0
09-02 16:51:11.891 31984-32036/com.thebhakti E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb7352a78 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
09-02 16:51:14.579 31984-31984/com.thebhakti E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.thebhakti, PID: 31984
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:3643)
                                                                   at com.thebhakti.RealtimeMain$2.onDataChange(RealtimeMain.java:71)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Compiler don't lie. Please check logcat for line number and object that is null.

Comment: i have uploaded my logcat in post

Comment: if i remove CharSequence then it shows error so how i retrieve value from database. or any necessarily modification in this code

Comment: try to debug the progam and check what is in postSnapshot. may be it helps

Comment: and one other issue with this code is that its send complete data when i changed something manually on database. it can't send only modified data

Comment: for that you can use childEventListner instead of valueEventListner

Comment: issue is remain same.issue is that how to receive value for particular child key. There is a field name so i want to retrieve value of name from database and want to append on textview so how it is possible

Comment: post your database hierarchy/structure

Comment: Value of `postSnapshot.child("name").getValue()` is `null` so you are not getting data from database.

Comment: so how i got data

Comment: Can u share your database structure @PradeepSheoran

Comment: How to post database structure image here

Comment: edit your question and add the image

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you want to update the data in `TextView txtMsg` when it is changed in the database. So the method you used will give following results which is not appropriate.

I am considering single name i.e. Akshay

```
txtMsg.append((CharSequence) postSnapshot.child("name").getValue());
```

It will give results - Akshay

Suppose you changed the name from Akshay to Punitt. So the name Punitt will be appended in txtMsg & the result will be-

AkshayPunitt

But the correct way would be that Akshay should be replaced by Punitt. So you should use the method `setText()` as shown-

```
txtMsg.setText(postSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is not a proper way, use model class to retrieve a data.
please refer this link
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write